# Using a for loop inside an onClickListener

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use a for loop inside of an onClickListener for a button. But if I use the `cursorCount`variable as condition it does not execute any of the code in the `onClick()` method. If I exchange `cursorCount` with a fixed value like `5`it works perfectly fine. I can also access the value of `cursorCount`at any given point before the for loop. `cursorCount`is increased every time a specific event occurs, which works fine. Button definition:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Previous"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.181"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_main_webview"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.556" />
```

Activity/onCreate:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webView;
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO = 693;
TextView noteText;
TextView pitchText;
String midiString;
int osmdMidiValue = 1;
int playedMidiValue = 1;
public int cursorCount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    noteText = findViewById(R.id.noteText);
    pitchText = findViewById(R.id.textView);

    // Check if permission is not granted
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Shows Pop-up
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO);

    }
    else{
        AudioDispatcher dispatcher =
                AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(22050, 1024, 0);
        PitchDetectionHandler pdh = new PitchDetectionHandler() {
                @Override
                public void handlePitch(PitchDetectionResult res, AudioEvent e) {
                    final float pitchInHz = res.getPitch();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            processPitch(pitchInHz);
                            if(pitchInHz!=-1) {
                                pitchText.setText(String.valueOf(pitchInHz));
                            }
                                    }
                        });
                 }
        };
        AudioProcessor pitchProcessor =
                new PitchProcessor(PitchProcessor.PitchEstimationAlgorithm.FFT_YIN, 22050, 1024, pdh);
        dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(pitchProcessor);

        Thread audioThread = new Thread(dispatcher, "Audio Thread");
        audioThread.start();
    }


    startDisplay();

    final Button startbtn = findViewById(R.id.button);
    startbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getMidiValue();
        }
    });

    final Button resetbtn = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    resetbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            webView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:resetCursor()");
            cursorCount=0;
        }
    });

    final Button prevbtn = findViewById(R.id.button3);
    prevbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int test = cursorCount;
            webView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:resetCursor()");
            for(int prevCount=0; prevCount<test; prevCount++){
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:nextValue()");
            }
        }
    });

}
```

`cursorCount`Value is changed here:

```
public void checkValue(){

    if(osmdMidiValue == playedMidiValue){
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:nextValue()");
        cursorCount++;
        getMidiValue();

    }
    else if(osmdMidiValue == 0){
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:nextValue()");
        cursorCount++;
        getMidiValue();
    }

}
```

Comment: what is cursorCount, show your declaration!

Comment: You are initialized your cursorCount as zero. Then how will it iterate?

Comment: `public int cursorCount = 0;` and just zero???

Comment: As I mentioned, `cursorCount` is is increased by another method. I already tried to get the value with `Log.d("Test", ""+cursorCount);` before the loop and I got the correct value.

Comment: Please provide all the code required to see the issue, as it is we can only guess the problem. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: If you want get help, show full code required

Comment: I added the entire `onCreate()`- and the `checkValue()`-method.

Answer (score 0):

Use local variable and not a field, so that every block starts with desired count.

Comment: I just tried putting `int test = cursorCount;`at the start of the `onClick()` Method and using `test` instead of `cursorCount`in the loop, if that's what you meant. I doesn't work however.